# How to specify typings path to tsify?

Tags: typescript, tsify

I have my typescript sources in the path:

```
src/game/ts
```

tsconfig.json is in:

```
src/game/ts/tsconfig.json
```

and typings in:

```
src/game/ts/typings
```

I can run tsc fine with:

```
tsc --p src/game/ts
```

But I get undefined type errors (for types declared in `src/game/ts/typings/**/*.d.ts` files) using this command:

```
browserify --debug src/game/ts/main.ts -p [ tsify --p src/game/ts ] > public/game/js/bundle.js
```

Why isn't tsc picking up the definitions? My tsconfig.json contains:

```
"include": [
    "main.ts", "typings/**/*.d.ts"
],
```

Answer (score 1):

To include the typings, you only need to add the `typings/index.d.ts` file, as it references the other `.d.ts` files in the `typings` directory. So a glob is not required and you can simply use the `files` option:

```
"files": [
    "main.ts",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`"include"` does not support `globs`. Please use the `filesGlob` option

## More

this option was only recently added. Use `nightly` : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/getting-started.html#typescript-version

Comment: I've tried both `filesGlob` and `include`. I've discovered I can make it work by passing each d.ts file in the command, although that makes for a very long command line. It doesn't seem to pick up the options from tsconfig.json either, so I have to add those as well. I'm guessing I cannot pass the project path through tsify.